# How to append and prepend text to a matched substring using regex

Tags: html, regex, perl

I was working with formatting a string in Perl with html tag.
Given a string S of pattern:

- net insider gain of xyz Rupees ..............

How to prepend `<p class="Green">`  and append `</p>` to convert string S to:

`<p class="Green">net insider gain of xyz</p> Rupees ...........`

?

What I have tried?
I tried to find the index of `net` and index of `of` and then concatenated `<p class="Green">` and `</p>`. But this method is bit slower.

Can you suggest better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regex substitution:

```
$S =~ s!\b(net insider\b.*?)( Rupees)!<p class="Green">$1</p>$2!;
```

*Gives:*

```
<p class="Green">net insider gain of xyz</p> Rupees
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this :

```
(net)(.*)(Rupess)(.*)
```

And replace by :  `<p class="Green">\1\2</p>\3\4`

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oB3oO8)**

In perl you can use `$1`,`$2`,`$3`,`$4` instead of `\1` `\2` `\3` `\4`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex to get the string you like

```
my $ip="net insider gain of xyz Rupess ..............";
if($ip =~ /(.*) Rupess (.*)/)
{
    print "<p class=\"Green\">$1</p> Rupess $2";
}
else
{
    print "no match..."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible answers to your question, ritesh, since you do not specify, logically, how this algorithm should function.  Instead all we have to go on is a string and make our best guess as to what other possible input values there may be.  I believe Radhuram may have it right - that "Rupees" is the best value to delimit the string on.  Given that, I would suggest:

```
my $S = 'net insider gain of xyz Rupees ..............';
$S =~ s{(.*)( Rupees)\b}{<p class="Green">$1</p>$2};
```

Which produces:

```
<p class="Green">net insider gain of xyz</p> Rupees ..............
```